# Removing 0th section of UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have UITableView.When view load i want to show the tableview without section.Also i have only one section of the tableview.I have referred much coding.But i am not satisfied with that.I have applied following coding in viewDidLoad.

```
 [tableviewSetting deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
 self.editing = YES;
```

Even i applied above coding in viewDidLoad,it does not change anything.So if you guys anyone help for me,it will be better.Please tell me the explanation of above coding.

Comment: Why don't you set numberOfSectionsInTableView to 1??? Sorry if I don't understand your question.

Comment: Are you setting Section Header to the tableView from xib in Size inspector tab??

Comment: No No.I set the tableview using plist and after that i set the custom cell for table view.Just i set the table view in xib.Thats all.

Comment: why would you want to delete the one and only section of your `tableView`? if you delete section 0 then your table is, \*poof\*, **gone**. Maybe you're trying to delete the first row or something like that?

Comment: I dont want any header section.It is showing the section.Thats y i want to delete that section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few questions

1. Are you using group table?
2. Its iOS 7?

If you need to remove unrequited space of section from top (normally it should not be there), then try following code. It might work

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0.01;
}
```